# Installing wordpress on a previous mysql installation. Users etc

Tags: wordpress, installation, xampp, bitnami

I'd like to install wordpress against my mysql database and tools installed for the dev work I usually do.

Firstly I used the XAMPP installer and checked all options except MySQL. All installed ok.

I've not installed phpadmin because it wasnt part of xampp and as I think it's just for admining mysql, which I can do through mysql admin, I don't believe I need it. I'm learning so if I'm wrong then pls tell me.

Now, I'm using Bitnami's windows installer for wordpress 4.0 beta 2.

A form asks me for login, real name, email address, "the existing mysql password for XAMPP",  "Enter the application password", "retype password".

I'm assuming that if I'd elected to install MySql via the XAMPP installer, it would have configured one or two users. But as I've not used that then I don't have a clue what the user names would be. Did it also install a database? Can anybody help here please? Googling it didn't bring me much help for my case.

Thanks :)

Comment: So you said you had a previous MySQL installation but don't know the password? I'm kind of confused here. You need to have MySQL setup for WordPress to use. Bitnami has some tools that set all that up for you, although I've found it to be annoying and cumbersome. Just installing XAMPP, including MySQL (and I use PHPMyAdmin), will ask you to configure a user.

Answer (score 2):

If you already had MySQL installed, just go ahead througth the mysql admin (as you mentioned) create a user, a database for your Wordpress installation and provide this data to the installer...